# Double Integral - Sketch region and evaluate

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Sketch the region of integration and evaluate the integral: 
$$\int_1^2 \int_y^{y^2} dx \, dy$$

I understand how to take the integral, but the region of integration seems like it has no bounds. Like between y=1 and y=2, the graphs of $y = \sqrt{x}$ and $y = x$ diverge, and don't form a closed region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region of integration is in fact bounded. First, we integrate with respect to $x$ over the interval of integration $[y,y^2]$. It's true that $y$ and $y^2$ diverge as $y\rightarrow\infty$. However, the bounds on the second integration w.r.t. $y$ are only from $y=1$ to $y=2$. Together, the region of integration in the $xy$-plane can be represented mathematically by the pair of inequalities:

$$y \leq x \leq y^2,\\
1 \leq y \leq 2.$$

Note that since $1 \leq y \leq 2$, it follows that $1 \leq y^2 \leq 4$. Going back to the first inequality with this bounds in mind,

$$1 \leq y \leq x \leq y^2 \leq 4$$.

Thus, the region of integration must be a subset of the rectangle $[1,4]\times[1,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

The region has $4$ bounds: lower bound $y = 1$, upper bound $y = 2$, left bound $x = y$, right bound $x = y^2$.

[image]